# While printing the table , the alignment of the table is not showing properly and the details are getting hide

Tags: css

The table details are showing properly when It shows before print, but when I print it the table data column is getting hidden or not showing properly when the page breaks

here is the Image url https://ibb.co/WkdB2xZ

I have tried some code on media print but that is not working here, please check this out my code , and tell  me where I am wrong

```
@media print {
  * {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.05em
  }
  table {
    page-break-inside: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    page-break-after: auto;
  }
  tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: auto;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  thead {
    display: table-header-group
  }
  tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group
  }
  td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
```

There is no response I am getting even I tried margin-bottom on td but this did not work

Comment: CSS Doesn't mean much without the HTML. Please provide a [MCVE]. I would also recomend reading the [help] and taking the [tour]